# Android building dynamic views

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have an application that will need call a webservice and build a list of Cards based on the response. I.E. The number and content of the cards is indefinite. So lets say that my response looks like this (note that this is a simplified response):

```
{
  "items": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5"
  ],
  "timestamp": "bla bla bla"
}
```

For each item in the array `items` a new Card needs be created. What is the most performance conscious way to do this? Should I just programmatically create all the cards and them add them in Java, use Fragments, or am I thinking incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the most performance conscious way to do this?

That is difficult to answer in the abstract, given that nobody here knows what "cards" are and nobody here knows what the "content" is. In general, the most performant way to create things is to not create them until they are needed.

In Android, for a vertically-scrolling list (my interpretation of "a list of cards") of moderately lightweight things, you would wrap your array of model data in an `ArrayAdapter` or `RecyclerView.Adapter`, for use with a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` respectively. Here, by "moderately lightweight", think tweets and the like.

For a vertically-scrolling list of heavyweight things... generally, just say no, as that's not a typical UX pattern on Android. Horizontal swiping is the typical approach for dealing with a collection of visually complex items. That typically uses a `ViewPager`, and typically uses fragments for pages. For a large collection (say, more than a half-dozen), use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, to cap the amount of heap space consumed by your UI. To draw a comparison, showing contact name + thumbnail would be lightweight and typically shown vertically scrolling in a `ListView`/`RecyclerView`. Showing the full contact details (larger photo, all email addresses, all phone numbers, etc.) would be handled via horizontal swiping using a `ViewPager`.

If Los Angeles will be blow'd up by a super-villain if you don't implement this in a vertical scrolling fashion *and* the items are heavyweight, there is at least one vertical `ViewPager` implementation floating around as a library, though I haven't used this.

Comment: Cards as in a `CardView` - http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html

Comment: @James_Parsons: That doesn't really change the answer. All `CardView` does is add rounded corners and a drop shadow to a collection of related widgets.

Comment: A little googling shows me that that the `ViewPager` is used in conjunction with tabs. Would it be ok (or even possible) to use a horizontal swiping pattern without tabs?

Comment: @James_Parsons: Sure. Tabs are used primarily when then category/topic/whatever of the content in a page is not intuitively obvious from the page itself. `ViewPager` itself does not supply tabs; it is eminently possible to use `ViewPager` without them.